# How to convert JSON (org.jooq.JSON) to Java Object (POJO)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jooq

I have tried lot of ways to find to convert JSON object (org.jooq) to java object (pojo). I am working on spring-boot application using jOOQ to talk with the database.

***Actually I have a employee_details table in database shown in below:***

[image]

In the above table has employee details, In that table emp_address column type  is JSON datatype

Now I want to retrieve the one employee_details from table where id=X and I tried to store the details in below java object class (POJO).

***EmployeeDetails class:***

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class EmployeeDetails {
    private int              id;
    private String           emp_name;
    private String           emp_email;
    private String           emp_mobile;
    private EmployeeAddress  emp_address;
}
```

***EmployeeAddress class:***

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class EmployeeAddress {

    private String hNo;
    private String city;
    private String pincode;
}
```

But when I try to retrieve the details from table I got store the emp_address(which is json datatype in table) in Json(org.jooq) as shown in below class.

***EmployeeDetailsJSONJooQ class:***

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.jooq.JSON;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class EmployeeDetailsJSONJooQ {
    private  int        id;
    private  String     emp_name;
    private  String     emp_email;
    private  String     emp_mobile;
    private  JSON       emp_address;
}
```

Here I want to retrieve the employee details in either EmployeeDetails object or help me to convert the EmployeeDetails object to EmployeeDetailsJSONJooQ object or how to map these objects using *Mapstruct*. Please help me out

Comment: `emp_name`, `emp_email`, etc you shouldn't name properties like this. Better stick to Java naming conventions and name them `empName`, `empEmail`, etc. Thus you can avoid much pain with libraries (Jackson, MapStruct and others) that do follow convention and expect proper names.

Comment: Yah, Thank you @Nikolai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not too opinionated on how the JSON should be mapped to your POJOs, it should suffice to place either Gson or Jackson on your classpath, and jOOQ will pick that up and map JSON to your POJOs automatically, see [this section of the manual about the `ConverterProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/converter-provider/).

E.g. this should work out of the box:

```java
List<EmployeeDetails> list =
ctx.selectFrom(EMPLOYEE_DETAILS)
   .fetchInto(EmployeeDetails.class);
```

Comment: What about the other way arround? POJOs to JSON?

Comment: @kylie.zoltan: Please ask a new question: I probably cannot answer this in the comments section here.

Comment: Is there a jOOQ alternative for this: objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employeeDetails)?

Comment: @kylie.zoltan: The comment section is really not a good place to answer this. Can you please ask a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask